# How to show progress in windows 7 taskbar (using Qt)?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

Is there a way to access the windows 7 progress bar with Qt? I'm currently using Qt 4.7.0 with Qt Creator.

I already found [Q7Goodies](http://www.strixcode.com/q7goodies/) but unfortunately it is not free. So it seems to be possible - how can I access to the progress bar by hand (without Visual Studio)?

Comment: ITaskbarList3::SetProgressValue().

Comment: See also [KDE Taskbar Progress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43875343/673852), where [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919667/673852) points to a [repository](https://github.com/Skycoder42/QTaskbarControl) with code that supports both KDE and Windows taskbar progress indicators. (I've actually checked it on both systems and can confirm that it works.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think they used Win7 API functions and encapsulated them in their library. You can include by hand those headers and use them too. Here you can find a help topic and demo project: [codeproject.com/KB/vista/SevenGoodiesTaskbarStatus.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/SevenGoodiesTaskbarStatus.aspx)

But its only for win7. Not crossplatform. Good luck

**update mar 05, 2014**

This question was asked a long time ago and many things have changed since. For those asking themselves the same question today (beginnings of 2014) then my personal answer is that Qt 5 fully supports progress in taskbar and different kind of beautiful extras. See [QWinTaskbarProgress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarprogress.html#details) (**upd nov 28, 2016**) for details

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't figured out how to do this yet, especially with the QtCreater it seems hard. Maybe someone is able to make use of that post: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26974-Qt-and-windows-7-new-Api?p=128880#post128880. I think I have to try it using Visual Studio...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`QWinTaskbarProgress`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarprogress.html) class. To use this class, you need to add `win32:QT += winextras` in your .pro file.

Here is an example code showing how to show the value of a `QProgressBar` in the Windows task bar ([inspired from this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarbutton.html#details)):

```
#ifdef _WIN32    //The _WIN32 macro is automatically generated when compiling for Windows
    #include <QWinTaskbarProgress>
    #include <QWinTaskbarButton>
#endif
QProgressBar *progressBar = new QProgressBar;
progressBar->show();
#ifdef _WIN32
    QWinTaskbarButton *windowsTaskbarButton = new QWinTaskbarButton;    //Create the taskbar button which will show the progress
    windowsTaskbarButton->setWindow(progressBar->windowHandle());    //Associate the taskbar button to the progress bar, assuming that the progress bar is its own window
    QWinTaskbarProgress *windowsTaskbarProgress = windowsTaskbarButton->progress();
    windowsTaskbarProgress->show();
    QObject::connect(loadingWindow, &QProgressBar::valueChanged, [windowsTaskbarProgress](int value){
        windowsTaskbarProgress->setValue(value);   //Change the value of the progress in the taskbar when the value of the progress bar changes
    });
#endif
```